# When MAP beats ADVI

Tags: bayesian, variational-bayes

I currently observed surprising results, I'd gratefully if someone could help me with understanding them. Unfortunately, I would not be able to share details of the data, nor of the discussed model, since both are proprietary, but I'll try giving as much details as possible.

I am working with a complicated Bayesian model, implemented in [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/). Due to computational reasons, we need to be using ADVI (Kucukelbir et al, [2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03431), [2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00788)), rather then MCMC. Additionally, we are using minibatches, since we observed them to speed up the training and improve the results (as measured by test set performance and posterior predictive checks). Since what we also need to do, is to be able to make the predictions on demand, we were exploring ways to speed up making the predictions, including using [maximum a posteriori (MAP)](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/tuning/starting.py#L39) estimate (using L-BFGS-B optimization), instead of sampling from posterior in such cases.

When I compared errors of the results obtained using MAP vs ADVI, I observed that *both* train and test root mean squared error were *lower* for MAP. The point estimates for ADVI were obtained by taking 5000 samples from the posterior distribution, making predictions based on them, and then taking mean of the predictions (but same results hold for median). This is pretty surprising, since ADVI is considered as a state of the art optimization method for such problems. What could be the potential reasons for such results?

Comment: I am not sure I follow everything you are doing, but you understand that advi   is an approximation with no performance guarantees.  See eg https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/06/27/yes-work-evaluating-variational-inference/.

Comment: @seanv507 yes, I've already read this, still I'm surprised that MAP beats it, until now I assumed that almost everything beats MAP.

Comment: Also see https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2020/02/13/how-good-is-the-bayes-posterior-for-prediction-really/, and follow on comments. Where advi was supposed to give better predictive performance than mcmc. ( Am guessing because advi 'by accident' regularised more)

Comment: @seanv507 thanks for the references, especially the second post & comments, it seems to answer my concerns. If the respected authors say that such behaviour does not surprise them, then I guess, I should accept that. Maybe you could convert the comments & expand into an answer?

Comment: hi @Tim , I'm really curious how the unnormalized posterior densities of each point estimate compare between the two. If its not too much of a hassle, do you mind sharing?

Comment: @silly.deer as said, I can't really share the details. Why would you consider them interesting?

Comment: @Tim (it's unrelated to your original question) i am interested because in high dimensions, most samples are going to from far from the mode. it would be interesting to see whether the bayes estimator yields an estimate that is near the (estimated) mode

Answer (score 0):

Taking the marginal means of posterior distributions tend to yield poor predictions in multimodal posteriors.

As an illustrative example, consider the 2D bimodal distribution below.
Taking marginal means of each will yield poor results, as your mean would land somewhere in the white/gray areas between the two modes. e.g., when X is at its mean at X=5, Y isn't necessarily concentrated at its mean Y=5, instead Y is mostly concentrated at around Y=7.

A better idea is to use the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution).
 Using posterior samples, this boils down to taking posterior sample $\theta_1$ and predict a single value $Z_1$. Do this for 5000 samples, and take the mean/median/mode of your $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_{5000}$ as your final prediction.

[image: 2D bimodal distribution]

Comment: I *was* taking means of the predictions. I edited to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the MAP estimate, a single set of parameters was returned, and that single model was used to predict new values?

Comment: Yes, MAP parameters were used to make predictions, for ADVI it was 5K samples of the parameters, to make 5K predictions, and then average the predictions per each datapoint.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the ADVI sample mode compare? (approximate mode)

Comment: I think a more equitable comparison of ADVI vs MAP would be to predict using the sample mode from ADVI predictions.

Comment: Taking mode in multidimensional data is a problem on it's own, so quality of the mode estimator would play it's part as well and I wanted to avoid it.